# How to create array and store values in it without knowing its size in Arduino

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm trying to write Arduino code for receiver that receives hexadecimal values from another Arduino (Transmitter), then I want to check this values and store them in new array which I don't know its size, while transmitter sends values receiver will store them.

Values reaches successfully to receiver but I don't know how to store them in new array.

My receiver code is like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
{
 if (receivedValue[i]==0x60)
          {
    //digitalWrite(LED1,LOW); 
    // store receivedValue[i] in the new array
          }
          else
          {
            if(receivedValue[i]==0x61)
            {
            //digitalWrite(LED3,LOW); 
             // store receivedValue[i] in the new array
            }

            if (receivedValue[i]==0x62)
            {
            //digitalWrite(LED4,LOW); 
              // store receivedValue[i] in the new array
          }

          // any other receivedValue[i] dont do anything
        }
    }
```

LEDs works successfully as I want but how to store them in array?

Answer (score 0):

Two approaches suggested:

1. Array pre-defined with fixed size

   ```
   #define MAX_ITENS 50       // The size of buffer
   uint8_t buffer[MAX_ITENS]; // The Buffer
   uint8_t posBuffer = 0;     // Pointer to actual position

   loop() {
       .... 
       // Add data to buffer
       posBuffer++;

       if (posBuffer == MAX_ITENS) {
           // Buffer overflow - You can set position to 0 
           // or give some error
       } else {
           buffer[posBuffer] = data; // Save the data
       }
   }
   ```
2. Use a dynamic array library I like [this one](https://github.com/zacsketches/Arduino_Vector).